# trying to get string value from getAttribute() in selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chai

I'm trying to get the string value of the element attribute `data-id` and store it into a variable

So that i can check to make sure the `data-id` is equal to the one that would load on the next page.

**Here is my code:

```
var dataId;

it('Should redirect to request details page, with the selected contract', function(done) {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.xpath('//*[@id="contracts-list-panel"]/div[2]/div'))).click();
    var element = driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="select-contract-modal"]/div[1]/div[2]/button'));
    dataId = element.getAttribute("data-id").then(function(attr) {
        expect(typeof attr).to.be.a("string");
        console.log(dataId.toString());
        element.click().then(function() {
            driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.id('request-new-signer-email'))).then(done());
        });
    });
});
```

The `console.log` returns this:

```
ManagedPromise::1356 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

Comment: You are being returned a promise and need to wait for it to resolve. You can either use the `.then()` syntax or [async/await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await)

Comment: I don't know why you would expect dataId to be available in that scope.  It isn't assigned until the return of that promise "element.getAttribute("data-id").then" and that promise doesn't resolve with a value either

Comment: @AndrewLively Thanks! I struggled for hours with this one.  I did not realize getAttribute returned a promise, and since I am using async/await, I have to await the result i.e. `const bodyClass = await body.getAttribute('class');`